# How can I find and replace only in a range of columns?

Tags: awk, sed, replace, text

I have a text file with 9267 lines.  I want to find "A" with 5 spaces after it and replace it with "A" with 5 spaces *before and after* it on all lines, but only between columns 67 and 88.  Text outside of those columns needs to be excluded.  I'm hoping `sed` and/or `awk` can be of help here, though I don't know how to use them very well.

---

Details: I'm converting a 128 page PDF into a spreadsheet.  I used PDFedit to save the PDF as a text file.  I'm planning to use LibreOffice to Insert a "Sheet from File".  That's proving to be difficult because while the columns in the PDF line up well, the spreadsheet-type columns aren't in quite the same text-file-type column throughout the text file.  Every 50 lines or so is analogous to a different PDF page, and that's where a spreadsheet-type column might move a few text-file-type columns to the left or right.  In other words, the spreadsheet-type column for "Shelf" might start on text-file-type column 70 in one part of the file, but start on text-file-type column 76 in another part.  That makes it so the spreadsheet-type columns overlap when I try to do a "Fixed Width" Insert into LibreOffice.  I want to make the columns more spread out by adding spaces via find and replace so I can tell LibreOffice where to define the columns.  If I find and replace on the whole file, I end up putting spaces where I don't want them.

---

Here's an fairly accurate example:

> ```
> Item Code             Active Description                                Store Room      Row      Shelf     Bin  On Hand   
>  38NUTZSL                Y      3/8"-16 HEX ZINC NUT                     B            03           C         2         0  
>  WELD-AL                 Y      WELD, ALUM. ROD, STICK OR SPOOL          A            01             B       2         68.25  
>  08300                   Y      WASHER, 7/8 CASE HARDENED 29/32 ID,1 3/4 OD  A            01        C            5         0
> ```

Comment: What is a delimiter between columns? Some simplified example with ~5 columns and a few lines would be helpful to understand the problem.

Comment: @jimmij: I added an example, thanks for the idea.  And, to answer your question, the only delimiter is a varying amount of spaces.

Comment: I'm afraid that if the values in the columns contains spaces and additionally columns are not aligned then the problem is not trivial anymore...

Comment: @jimmij: That's why I'm asking for help.  :-)  I don't need to make the columns line up, I just need to separate them enough to tell LibreOffice what it should think a column is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better way to change the column separator and use `column`command:

```
sed 's/   */;/g' file | column -ts';'
```

which produce:

```
Item Code  Active  Description                                  Store Room  Row  Shelf  Bin  On Hand
 38NUTZSL  Y       3/8"-16 HEX ZINC NUT                         B           03   C      2    0
 WELD-AL   Y       WELD, ALUM. ROD, STICK OR SPOOL              A           01   B      2    68.25
 08300     Y       WASHER, 7/8 CASE HARDENED 29/32 ID,1 3/4 OD  A           01   C      5    0
```

Comment: Thanks, @Costas.  That makes things look much nicer.  I'll need to do some manual fixing in addition, but that's a great start.  Could you update your answer explaining how the command works?

Comment: @mikeserv: could you expand on that some more?  Are you suggesting that I don't use sed, and only use tr, or pipe sed into tr?

Comment: @mikeserv if there are not spaces in "Description"-column the `tr` could be OK but …

Comment: @mikeserv But in the case there are some spaces in 3rd column

Comment: @Costas - very good point.